# Change Cart and Checkout Summary - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to change the text by adding fields and removing others on the summery cart and the checkout summary. The changes I would like to make are explained in this image.
[image]
But basically I would like to add a total (which would be the sum of the product prices), and I would like to add a 'final total' field which would be the total minus the discount. Then I would like to remove those two fields that I marked.

I tried messing with the php file, but it was a disaster

Comment: I used WP Deposits plugin for strings 4) and 5)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Bhautik I tried to edit the woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php file by changing the string 'Subtotal' to 'Total' and changing <?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?> with <?php wc_cart_totals_html(); ?>